# Вопрос про создание интерфейсов и их реализацию

Tags: c#, ооп, интерфейс, .net

Не могу понять как выбирается случай для использования следующих интерфейсов. Допустим нужно реализовать отправку файла. Стоит создавать интерфейс по типу:

```cs
interface ICustomFileSender
{
    Task SendByEmailAsync(CustomFile file);
    Task SendByHttpAsync(CustomFile file);
}
```

и дальше его реализовывать, либо создать интерфейс по типу:

```cs
interface ICustomFileSender
{
    Task SendAsync(CustomFile file);
}

class CustomEmailFileSender : ICustomFileSender
{
    //Реализация 
}
```

От чего следует отталкиваться одного из перечисленных интерфейсов?

Comment: Суть интерфейсов в том, что вы можете использовать различную логику тогда, когда вам это нужно, не меняя весь код. Если у вас вдруг появиться отправка файла, например на FTP сервер, что тогда? Будете менять интерфейс, попутно исправляя все другие классы, что его реализуют? К тому же, первый ваш вариант, нарушает SOLID, а именно SRP - единстенная ответственность, ибо он вдруго становиться ответсвенным и за почту и за http.

Comment: В соответствии с SOLID это плохо спроектированный интерфейс, нарушен принцип сегрегации интерфейсов: нужно разбить на два отдельных интерфейса и ооооочень большой вопрос нужен ли будет составной интерфейс. В тестах например (а тестирование и моки -- это один из самых типовых кейсов, когда "различная логика" и нужен интерфейс) вы явно будете мокать по отдельности и тестировать раздельно. А вот класс отправки нужно ли объявлять как реализующий комбо-интерфейс - не факт, что понадобится. PS А вопрос ваш непонятен, потому все отвечают в комментариях.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Ага, вижу кто-то забыл букву I в слове SOLID ;-) А пример-то классический между прочим. Хотите хороший пример вот прям из реальных? Я подписан на блог Джимми Богарда, автора AutoMapper и Mediatr, у него был хороший пост как он в девятой (зрелый продукт, несколько лет и много версий... и вот всё равно не сразу было очевидно такое изменение) версии Mediatr всё же решил разделить интерфейс: https://jimmybogard.com/mediatr-9-0-released/

Comment: Спасибо, теперь понял почему не стоит использовать первый вариант.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В первом случае, чтобы добавить канал доставки, вам придется изменять интерфейс, и код, который с ним взаимодействует.

```cs
interface ICustomFileSender
{
    Task SendByEmailAsync(CustomFile file);
    Task SendByHttpAsync(CustomFile file);
    Task SendByFtpAsync(CustomFile file);
    Task SendBySmsAsync(CustomFile file);
    Task SendByTelegramAsync(CustomFile file);
    Task SendByViberAsync(CustomFile file);
}
```

Следовательно, второй вариант выглядит правильно, только я бы немного переименовал метод, чтобы название отражало его суть.

```cs
interface ICustomFileSender
{
    Task SendFileAsync(CustomFile file);
}
```

Интерфейс - это абстракция, которая по своей сути позволяет вам без ошибок реализовать наследующий класс (код не скомпилируется, если класс не полностью реализует интерфейс), плюс позволяет вам добавлять разные реализации, не меняя остальной код. Создаете еще один реализующий класс, закидываете экземпляр класса в коллекцию, и готово.

```cs
List<ICustomFileSender> allSenders = GetAllSenders();
CustomFile file = OpenCustomFile();
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
foreach (ICustomFileSender sender in allSenders)
{
    tasks.Add(sender.SendFileAsync(file));
}
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Comment: Спасибо! Понял!